# Did I understand the criteria for "Bill Lumbergh" hat correctly?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

I'm a big, big fan of the Hats. :-)

However, as I read, the "Bill Lumbergh" hat should be given to someone who

> answer 5 questions on a Saturday (in UTC time)

Well, I did so, and still the hat is not showing up in my collection. Can anybody share what is going on? Is there any other criteria (related to any other Time Zone, or a particular timeout period after posting answers)?

*P.S - Please pardon my eagerness.*

Comment: This is a valid support question; we'll get one of these for every hat with a posting requirement. Downvoting them might hide them and only lead to duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [implicit quality requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer/245123#245123) for hats tied to posting:

> To prevent people from posting nonsense just to earn a hat, most hats that require creating content, especially questions and answers, have some requirements that may not be mentioned in the hat description. Generally this involves questions/answers having a positive score (i.e. getting at least one upvote), not being closed/deleted, etc.

Your 5 answers must all score 1 or more; so far only 3 of your answers today meet that criterion.

Don't worry, if those votes come tomorrow or later, but still within the Winter Bash period, you'll still be awarded the hat then.

Comment: Thank you Martijn for your quick reply. I see the point now and totally agree to it. Just asking, accepted-but-zero-scored answers don't count in this, right? Can't ask people to upvote, either. Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: if accepting counted you'd already have the hat. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I hope so. Cheers to winter bash 2014. :-)

Comment: The reputation requirement should be explicitly stated. If it was just one answer required, everybody could reasonably assume it had to be well-received, but if it's five answers in one day, I think the rep requirement should be explicit.

(...I really feel like we need to rename hats to flair, and then give a prize for anybody who has more than 15 pieces of flair.)